# janusgraph-full-1.0.0-rc1 : logs shows muiltiple Gauges message, want to know why those are coming and how it can be avoided if unnecessary

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I see multiple messages of Gauges coming in my JanusGraph logs, so want to check uses of these and how can I stop those.

```
> 11/28/23, 5:38:11 AM 
=========================================================== 
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.gremlin-groovy.sessionless.class-cache.average-load-penalty
  value = 8.184896446666666E8
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.gremlin-groovy.sessionless.class-cache.estimated-size
  value = 3
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.gremlin-groovy.sessionless.class-cache.eviction-count
  value = 0
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.gremlin-groovy.sessionless.class-cache.eviction-weight
  value = 0
org.apache.tierpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.gremlin-groovy.sessionless.class-cache.hit-count
  value = 0
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.gremlin-groovy.sessionless.class-cache.hit-rate
  value = 0.0
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.gremlin-groovy.sessionless.class-cache.load-count
  value = 3
```

Want to check, how it can be achieved.

Comment: Hello, I'm not quite sure what you are asking. Is the question about (a) what the logs mean, (b) how to disable logging, (c) both of these, or (d) something else? I reformatted the question a bit to make the logs easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can control all of the metrics reporting options in the [server yaml file](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.7.1/gremlin-server/conf/gremlin-server.yaml#L38) under `metrics`. Essentially:

```
metrics: {
  consoleReporter: {enabled: false, interval: 180000},
  csvReporter: {enabled: false, interval: 180000, fileName: /tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv},
  jmxReporter: {enabled: false},
  slf4jReporter: {enabled: false, interval: 180000}}
}
```

In the example above I just set `enabled` to `false` for all of them, but you could obviously be more selective in how you choose to do that.